# license enforcement system has been tampered with - win server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, licensing

On our production server, win 2008 32 bit, running a mvc 3 .NET 4 site,
I suddenly get this message in the error log
"server cannot open this program because the license enforcement system has been tampered with or become corrupted"

All software is licensed and I havent installed anything new on the server for some time (weeks).

The exception is thrown when calling a controller method when a object is serialized to XML.
Se extract from stacktrace below.

Does anyone have an idea of how to find out what's wrong here?

Best regards and TIA 
/Staffan

```
            from the Stacktrace:    at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
               at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
               at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.Compile(CompilerParameters options, String compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String arguments, String& outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue, String trueArgs)
               at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)
               at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
               at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
               at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
               at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
               at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
               at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
               at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, Type[] extraTypes, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I've found it

Looking at the stacktrace and seeing that the crash occurs at the CodeDom compiling a temporary assembly for Xml serializing, I googled this and up came following page 
[Error consuming Web Service from Winform App - "Cannot execute a program..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268/error-consuming-web-service-from-winform-app-cannot-execute-a-program) and it directed me to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx.

There it says, loud and clear, that memory leaks will occur if you use wrong constructors for XmlSerializer. With crashes like our as a possibly result.

So, after a rewrite of our Xml serializing service, I now enjoy NOT having these crashes and an impressive performance boost as it comes to Xml serializing.

/Z